# Algorithm to check if byte is 0x00 or 0xFF

Tags: c, boolean-logic

Is there a logical equivalent to:

<strike>`if(byte != 0x00 || byte != 0xFF)`</strike>

```
if(byte != 0x00 && byte != 0xFF)
```

I'm at my program memory limit and can use every optimalisation :)

To explain with words, can you check with a logic function if all bits are same (so all 0 or all 1)?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, it's equivalent to `if (true)`

Comment: Also, how does optimizing this improve memory?

Comment: @Shahbaz Many things can be done in multiple ways, some requiring more code, some less.

Comment: @Shahbaz: optimizing it *for small code* helps with the limit for *program memory*. It's possible the questioner means something different, but reducing binary size is a real concern, especially on embedded targets. Then again, it's not going to save more than a few bytes if anything, and asking this question is a lot of effort for a few bytes (and maybe nothing)...

Comment: @SteveJessop, right. I mistakenly thought he wants to reduce his memory usage for example because he is running out of stack memory. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `byte` has an unsigned 8-bit type [Edit: and assuming you meant `&&`, not `||`], you could try:

```
!((uint8_t)(byte+1) <= 1)
```

Obviously it's not possible to say whether this will produce smaller code, you just have to try it and see. No doubt other people can come up with other logically-equivalent expressions.

You can also look at what your compiler has produced, and if you suspect that your compiler's optimization isn't very good look at what other, better compilers produce. That might give you ideas for other expressions that are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe `(unsigned char)(byte + 1) > 1`? Assuming you mean `&&`, of course. And assuming that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, if you want "all bits set" to mean `0xFF`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's false for *three* values of `byte`, including `1`. Looks like the answerers have managed three different mistakes already ;-)

Comment: (I made two, but got rid of one of them before the edit window)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Should have been `1`. Thanks.

Comment: actually, the cast takes up much resources (8 bytes), without, i can save 2 bytes, thanks

Comment: @JonathanVervaeke: It's strange that I never asked, but what is the *type* of `byte`? If you make it `unsigned char` from the start, you don't need the cast.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What? You need either the cast or a mask with `0xFF`, because `((unsigned char)0xFF)+1` is greater than 1, because it's promoted to `int`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Oh, that's true. Not my day today :-( I'm not sure if the machine code will benefit in any way from starting with an unsigned char variable...

Answer (score 2):

The condition is always true.

<strike>I seriously doubt that the above check can be compacted much.</strike>

At the instruction level the if would look something like:

```
; if(byte != 0x00 || byte != 0xFF) 
cmp byte, 0
jnz ifbody
cmp byte, 0xFF
jz skipifbody
ifbody:
;{
; if body
;}
skipifbody:
```

There are about 4 instructions here. There isn't much to optimize here.

I would look for other places in the code to optimize things for size. The first thing to look at would be the data, not the code, though.

Answer (score 2):

I found that given your original code GCC is smart enough to produce something similar to Kerrek SB's answer when using `-O2`:

```
movzbl  8(%ebp), %eax
subl    $1, %eax
cmpb    $-3, %al
setbe   %al
```

which is basically equivalent to:

```
((unsigned char)byte - 1) <= -3 // or 0xFD
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's the C51 compiler